# How to find Qt library location

Tags: python, dll, path, pyqt, pyqt5

After importing the PyQt5 module with:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

I can find where the module is by simply:

```
print QtWidgets
```

prints:

```
<module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so'>
```

But aside from `PyQt5` module there is a Qt library. This Qt library is a set of precompiled binary files residing somewhere else on a disk. Their file names usually contain a word "Qt5" in a middle, for e.g: `libQt5Core.dylib`, `libQt5DesignerComponents.dylib` or `libQt5Script.dylib`.

Is there a way to get the file path to this Qt library from inside of Python after PyQt5 module is imported? How to find out where Python looks for the Qt library files needed by PyQt5 module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files like `libQt5Core.dylib` are shared libraries which are dynamically linked at runtime. When an executable requiring such libraries is created, the compile-time linker simply records the name of the library and whatever routines it provides that are needed by the application. It is the job of the operating system to perform the dynamic linking when the application is run.

Unix systems usually provide a tool that can determine the dependencies required by an executable, and show where they are currently located on the system. On Linux, this tool is called `ldd` (List Dynamic Dependencies), and the equivalent command on OSX would be `otool -L`. The output looks something like this:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd351e7000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f1cdc1c5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1cdbe3e000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1cdba87000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1cdb869000)
    ...
```

From Python, you can simply use the `subprocess` module to run the appropriate command, and then parse the output to get the information you require.